# Convert pandas DataFrame to 2-layer nested JSON using groupby

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, object

Assume that I have a pandas dataframe called `df` similar to:

```
source      tables
src1        table1       
src1        table2          
src1        table3       
src2        table1        
src2        table2
```

I'm currently able to output a JSON file that iterates through the various sources, creating an object for each, with the code below:

```
all_data = [] 

    for src in df['source']:
        source_data = {
            src: {
            }
        }
        all_data.append(source_data)

    with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(all_data, f, indent = 2)
```

This yields the following output:

```
[
  {
    "src1": {}
  },
  {
    "src2": {}
  }
]
```

Essentially, what I want to do is also iterate through those list of sources and add the table objects corresponding to each source respectively. My desired output would look similar to as follows:

```
[
  {
    "src1": {
      "table1": {},
      "table2": {},
      "table3": {}
    }
  },
  {
    "src2": {
      "table1": {},
      "table2": {}
    }
  }
]
```

Any assistance on how I can modify my code to also iterate through the tables column and append that to the respective source values would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
data = [
    {k: v} 
    for k, v in df.groupby('source')['tables'].agg(
        lambda x: {v: {} for v in x}).items()
]

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

There are two layers to the answer here. To group the tables by source, use `groupby` first with an inner comprehension. You can use a list comprehension to assemble your data in this specific format overall.

```
[
  {
    "src1": {
      "table1": {},
      "table2": {},
      "table3": {}
    }
  },
  {
    "src2": {
      "table1": {},
      "table2": {}
    }
  }
]
```

---

**Example using `.apply` with arbitrary data**

```
df['tables2'] = 'abc'

def func(g): 
    return {x: y for x, y in zip(g['tables'], g['tables2'])}

data = [{k: v} for k, v in df.groupby('source').apply(func).items()]
data
# [{'src1': {'table1': 'abc', 'table2': 'abc', 'table3': 'abc'}},
#  {'src2': {'table1': 'abc', 'table2': 'abc'}}]
```

Note that this will not work with pandas 1.0 (probably because of a bug)

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly, thank you! Assuming I'd need to take this a step further and also add a list of columns within each respective table (similar to how the list of tables was added to the respective source), how would I be able to do this though?

Comment: @weovibewvoibweoivwoiv Change `agg` to `apply` in the `groupby` condition, and then you can do arbitrary stuff with your data there, similar to how I've shown you.

Comment: not quite sure I see how exactly this works yet. If you don't mind, can you append this extra step to your original answer? Would be really helpful, thanks

Comment: @weovibewvoibweoivwoiv There is a bug in pandas 1.0 that prevents such expressions, what is your version? I've added an example. Hope it helps you.

Comment: I don't have pandas 1.0 so the code runs fine. However, the output isn't exactly the same as what I'm asking for. Looking for something more like ```[{'src1': {'table1': {'col1':{}, 'col2':{}}, 'table2': {'col1':{}, 'col2':{}, 'col3':{}}}]``` Essentially the same as before with just the srcs and tables but now with another column layer as well. Can we take this to private messages?

Comment: @weovibewvoibweoivwoiv I know it's probably not what you're looking for, but you can always modify `func` to return what you want. If you can't figure it out, feel free to open another question. Good luck!